# need a way to change server address after generating minified dist contents in gulp angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, gulp, minify

I am using [angular-gulp](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) repository for my angular js app which is working fine. One problem I am facing is in changing server address after giving the build to the client.

As of now in `index.constants.js`, I have given  `.constant('serverUrl', "http://x.y.z.a:6061");` and refering `serverUrl` in my services. I am generating `gulp serve:dist` and giving the minified version of the code to the client. Now the client wants to change the server address?

I am not clear how to proceed providing the way to the client to change their server ip address after I have given the dist contents.

Comment: I don't know about your client needs, can you externalise your constants to a configuration file (.env file json or yaml) ?

Comment: Yes, I can externalise my constants. But I don't have access to their server side code to use yaml file, etc. I handle only UI code and then bundle the code and give to them. In essence, after bundling, we should have an external file in UI code itself in which they should be able to change the server address and the already bundled code should be able to point to that updated address.

Comment: Yes you should have an external file in UI App that can be modified later by your client. You can use json for that and load it in your config module later... If you want to let your client change JS file you can exclude your config.js module from minification and load it in index.html like your minified and concatenated main.js.